# Swift - Load next view controller if already registered

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

When I run my app if the user is already registered(checking from the local database) I want to load a different ViewController. It is working but I see the previous screen for a split second and want to get rid of that. If I put the following code in the viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad it does not work. When I put it in ViewDidAppear it works and loads the next screen. How can I do this without seeing the screen for a split second?

This works but I see the previous screen for a split second.

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if(userInfo.Confirmed == "Yes") {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "skipRegistration", sender: self)

    }

}
```

This does not work:

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

```
    if(userInfo.Confirmed == "Yes") {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "skipRegistration", sender: self)

    }
}
```

And this does not work:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if(userInfo.Confirmed == "Yes") {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "skipRegistration", sender:
```

self)

```
    }

}
```

Thanks!

You can do this code in appdelegate in appLaunch method and push your viewcontroller  two time with no animation

**NOTE** Maintain your viewController stack properly.

Not understanding how to push the viewController.

I have the code inserted into appDelegate and I am trying to call the correct Controller to take over but can’t seem to find it. I have a tab bar controller and I have a navigation controller. It goes like this.

A registered user should skip to first screen of the app.

Not registered user gets these pages:

registration Screen

registration1 Screen

registration2 Screen

Agreement: Screen -> taps on accept agreement button then goes to:

```
Agreement segue -> (beginApp segue) to tab bar controller then goes to

Navigation Controller -> myFirst Screen of the App!
```

Everything is working but I need to skip to the first screen of the App.

I’ve tried using this sample code but can’t figure it out.

```
let navVC: UINavigationController =  rootView.viewControllers![4] as! UINavigationController


let vc = navVC.topViewController as! MoreTableViewController
```

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Can you clarify, and number or name each view controller? Also, where are you putting the posted code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this code in appdelegate in appLaunch method and push your viewcontroller  two time with no animation

**NOTE** Maintain your viewController stack properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is working!

```
// This works to load my tab bar controller and it works!
        let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController : UITabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "startHere") as! UITabBarController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```